# iptables send packet on blocked port using nat

Tags: iptables, routing

I am trying `curl --request GET http://10.0.0.4:80/path` but there exists a rule to drop output on port 80.

`iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/8 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP`

To counter this, I tried to send curl request through port 8888, bypassing iptables output chain then creating a iptables nat rule `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 8888 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80`  to change the destination port to 80 but I get

`Failed to connect to 10.0.0.4 port 8888: Connection refused`
How can I send the query by bypassing rule AND not creating an exception to the drop rule.

iptables -L

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8           tcp dpt:http`

iptables -L -t nat

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             10.0.0.4             tcp dpt:8888 tcp to:10.0.0.4:80`

Comment: are you missing an appropriate forward rule maybe? like ```iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 10.0.0.4 --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT```   maybe you could share your whole iptables setup?

Comment: I updated question including complete iptables. I tried your forwarding solution as well  `curl --interface eth0 --request  GET http://10.0.0.4:80/path` Dload remains 0 and 'Time Spent' is incremented

Comment: ok, first: your default action is ```ACCEPT``` on the ```OUTPUT``` swell as on the ```FORWARD``` Chain, so we don't need the explicit ACCEPT rules on both chains. What Does ```$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward``` print out?

Comment: Also, maybe the ```DNAT``` needs to be put in the ```PREROUTING``` Chain!?

Answer (score 0):

I now had some time and tested it out

`iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 8888 -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80`

Downside is that it can only be don't to a single target IP address/port (destination match can be an entire subnet, but DNAT address has to be a single address)

EDIT:

I see.
The Problem with our connection is that the output rule is one of the last stages in iptables, so it will always match a packet as it evaluates AFTER the `DNAT`. (As seen in [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/1000/1*OIoNQkH4RTSm-eY2lUMBcQ.jpeg) graph)

`POSTROUTUNG` cain, which would apply **AFTER** the `OUTPUT` Chain is not able to handle DNAT as stated in my dmesg output
`x_tables: ip_tables: DNAT target: used from hooks POSTROUTING, but only usable from PREROUTING/OUTPUT`

So I guess your request is not *fulfill able* as, to the firewall, the packet will always want to travel to port 80 which is, on its way out, Denied by the `OUTPUT` chain.

Comment: I updated my IP tables to reflect your changes. `curl --request GET http://10.0.0.4:80` and `curl --request GET http://10.0.0.4:8888` hang.  Inserting OUTPUT rule `ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.0.0.4` both curl queries return sucessfully but I don't want to create an exception to the DROP OUTPUT rule